# When exactly(and earliest) have all the block devices been enumerated during Linux Boot?

Tags: linux, rhel, kernel, block-device, sysfs

Problem:
During The Linux Boot, I want to know a certain instance  of time, when all the block devices have been enumerated. I assume the block devices are NOT  coming via a network( like iscsi), but come via FC, and could even be "multipath devices".

What I know:

If write a some script and set it up like

kernel.hotplug=MyScript and place it at /etc/sysconfig/MyScript.modules (notice the .modules extension).

I will get the devpath names of the devices being enumerated.

But this approach is not efficient.

Example : I want to act on the block devices have a different type of signature.

But, MyScript will get called all the times whenever any block device will be added to the system ( specifically whenever any kobject will be created/removed).

What I want  do is:

Another instance in the boot sequence when I know that all the block devices attached are available, so that I can just find the block devices I  like and do something I want with them.

Also, Notice that, I cannot wait till the xyz.service are enabled, which is quite late in the boot sequence.

Edit : Assume no systemd.
Linux uses the old(init) way of booting.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ systemctl status systemd-udev-settle
● systemd-udev-settle.service - udev Wait for Complete Device Initialization
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/systemd-udev-settle.service; static; vendor preset: disabled)

$ systemctl --reverse list-dependencies systemd-udev-settle.service
systemd-udev-settle.service
● └─dmraid-activation.service

$ systemctl cat dmraid-activation.service
# /usr/lib/systemd/system/dmraid-activation.service
[Unit]
Description=Activation of DM RAID sets
DefaultDependencies=no
Conflicts=shutdown.target
After=systemd-udev-settle.service
Before=lvm2-activation-early.service cryptsetup.target local-fs-pre.target shutdown.target
Wants=systemd-udev-settle.service
```

Try copying the relevant lines from dmraid-activation.service above.  This includes `DefaultDependencies=no`, since you insist on being as early as possible.  It is documented in `man systemd.unit` (refers to `systemd.service`.  Also you should read `man bootup`.

Comment: I should have added, What if there is no systemd, the system has old way of(init) way of booting.

Comment: you certainly should.  then you get to write an init script with a header that indicates it's dependence on the udev-settle init script.  This could potentially be forwards-compatible with systemd - provided the scripts being depended on all have service equivalents with the same (or [aliased](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=systemd+alias)) names.

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: There is generic reference information at http://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/LSB_3.1.0/LSB-Core-generic/LSB-Core-generic/tocsysinit.html